# creating a nested list from flat list with defined dimension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

i have a flat list that i want to transform into nested list based on the defined dimension, the length of the flat list can be arbitrary, but the dimension should satisfy the length of the list, for example

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

will produce a nested list

```
m = 2
n = 4
[[0,1][2,3][4,5][6,7]]
```

or

```
m = 4
n = 2
[[0,1,2,3][4,5,6,7]]
```

i am thinking of using list comprehension to generate the nested list, but other option can also appending element from the flat list

```
a = [[i] * m for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
m = 2
n = 4
nums = [i*m for i in range(1,n+1)]
[list(range(x,y)) for x, y in  zip([0] + nums, nums)]
```

**OR**

```
nums = [i*m for i in range(n)]
[list(range(z,z+m)) for z in (nums)]
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

---

**For**

```
m = 4
n = 2
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using list comprehensions:

```
col = list(range(10))
[
    col[col.index(val):col.index(val) + m]
    for val in col[::len(col)//n]
]
```